# Adding PowerShell progress bar increased execution time by x20 times

Tags: powershell

I put together a small script to alter huge text files (usually containing 500K+ lines).  It works kinda OK and time it takes to complete operation seems acceptable...but later on I tried adding a progress bar to it and tested on a relatively smaller text file(30K line).  execution time without progress bar and with was about 14 seconds and 289 seconds respectively.

This script is meant to delete everything except numeric character between 11 and 14 length and then remove duplicate lines from remaining ones.

```
       $lines = Get-Content *.txt
$totalL = $lines.count
$i = 0
$lines | 
Where-Object {$_ -Match '\b([0-9]{11,14})\b'} | 
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Progress -PercentComplete (
       $i*100/$totalL) -Activity "Lines completed: $i/$totalL"  -Status 'Working'
    $_ -replace '.*(\b([0-9]{11,14})\b).*', '$1'
       $i++ } | 
sort | get-unique | 
Set-Content Final_Unique.txt
```

I'm completely new at PowerShell.  I need help to better optimize this noob script and keep execution time to the minimum while keeping the progress bar.

Comment: From what I remember the progress bar is painfully slow in powershell. You might be much better of just using a counter and writing the current line to console all 100 or 1000 lines. Don't know if that would be an acceptable substitute for you?

Comment: Also as a sidenote, `Sort-Object` has a `-Unique` flag which would be more efficient than the separate `Get-Unique`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21305144/1244910 - you shouldn't call Write-Progress as frequently.

Comment: Linux has a 'pv' command that suffers not from slow performance.   Maybe you can get the 'pv' command on your PATH?